# When I use batch to reduce API calls, I miss some entries, how to fix the problem?

Tags: python, optimization, batch-processing

## Retrieve quotes in batches

```
batch_size = 80
for i in range(0, len(results), batch_size):
    batch = results[i:i + batch_size]
    codes = [(stock['shsz'], stock['stockCode'].strip()) for stock in batch]

    quotes = api.get_security_quotes(codes)

    if quotes is not None:
        for result, quote in zip(batch, quotes):
            if quote is None:
                stock_code = result['stockCode'].strip()
                print(f"Stock code {stock_code} returned None type.")
                continue  # Skip None types

            stock_code = result['stockCode'].strip()
            market = result['shsz']
            quote_df = api.to_df(quote)  # Convert the quote to a DataFrame
            price = quote_df['price'].iloc[0]  # Get the first price from the DataFrame
            if stock_code == '000697':
                print('000697 exists in stock_code')
```

'000697' doesn't appear when I execute the code, however, if I don't use batch, I recall `api.get_security_quotes` one by one, then '000697' appears.

Comment: The behaviour will depend very much on what the *api* class does